# difference between наиболее and самый + adjective

Tags: прилагательные

I have read this sentence:
"*какие професии **наиболее** востребованы?*",
which translates 
"Which jobs are the most needed?".

so here "the most (+ adjective)" is rendered with *наиболее*.

My problem is: to translate "the most..." I have always said **"самый + adjective"**.

Now I am confused. Why did they use *наиболее*? 
 Could it be possibile to write here *"самые востребованы"*? Are they interchangable?

If so, how can I make a form similar to наиболее with other adjecives?

Answer (score 4):

An adjective (or an attributive pronoun like "самый") is not used to modify a **short version** of an adjective or participle like "*востребован*", "*болен*", "*бел*", etc.  Olny **an adverb** would do.  An adverb can, of course, modify the full form of the same adjective.

Examples:

> **весёлый** -- *самый* весёлый, ***but*** **весел** -- *предельно<sub>adverb</sub>* весел (cannot say *самый весел*, but can say *предельно* весёлый)
>   **глупый** -- *самый* глупый, ***but*** **глуп**  -- *неописуемо<sub>adverb</sub>* глуп (cannot say *самый глуп*, but can say *неописуемо* глупый)

Answer (score 3):

> I have always said "самый + adjective"

There are two forms of superlative in Russian: simple (using suffixes *-айш-* or *-ейш-*, and, optionally, the prefix *наи-*) and complex one. To form a complex superlative you also have a couple of variants using either: *самый*, or *наиболее*, or *наименее* + adjective/participle.

Yet what you have here is *the short form* (*востребованы*), which prohibits the usage of the adjective *самый*. That is the possible combinations are: *наиболее востребованные*, *наиболее востребованы*, *самые востребованные*.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно - "Самые востребованы".
Правильно - "Самые востребованные".

"Why did they use наиболее?"
Я не знаю и никто не знает. :)

Excuse my English.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, наиболее is a bit more formal than самый. In terms of meaning I would say they're interchangeable. 
Anyway, keep in mind that наиболее is an adverb, while самый is an adjective, so the latter must be declined.
The two possible options are: 1. наиболее востребованы 2. самы**е** востребован**ные**

PS: I'm not Russian, so it might not be 100% correct :)